# ordering list of coordinates on row basis

Tags: python

I am trying to order a set of coordinates in a specific way

If I have a yet-to-be ordered set of coordinates that represent different cells in some grid,

```
{(2, 2), (3, 1), (1, 2), (3, 2), (1, 3)}
```

My goal is to order this from left to right starting from the bottom row.

```
schematic of coordinates

  0 1 2 3 4 
0 X X X X X
1 X X O O X
2 X X O X X
3 X O O X X


{(3, 1), (3, 2), (2, 2), (1, 2), (1, 3)} # desired output
```

I came up with the following code, but this would fail in the case where the row number is same but column number is different

```
data = {(1, 2), (1, 4), (2, 2), (0, 3), (0, 4)}

data_1 = sorted(data, key=lambda x: x[0], reverse=True)

data_2 = sorted(data_1, key=lambda x: x[1])

>>> print(data_2)
[(2, 2), (1, 2), (0, 3), (1, 4), (0, 4)]

# desired output
[(2, 2), (1, 2), (1, 4), (0, 3), (0, 4)]
```

What improvement can I make?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data = {(1, 2), (1, 4), (2, 2), (0, 3), (0, 4)}
sorted(data, key=lambda x:(-x[0],x[1]))
#[(2, 2), (1, 2), (1, 4), (0, 3), (0, 4)]
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
def sorted(items):
 for i in range(len(items)-1, 0 , -1):
  for j in range(i):
   if items[j][0] < items[j+1][0]:
    items[j], items[j+1] = items[j+1], items[j]
    continue
   if items[j][0] == items[j+1][0] and items[j][1] > items[j+1][1]:
    items[j], items[j+1] = items[j+1], items[j]
 return items


data = [(1, 2), (1, 4), (2, 2), (0, 3), (0, 4)] 
print(sorted(data))
```